# how to migrate seemlessly from information_schema to sys/performance_schema

Tags: mysql-5.7

I am migrating my mysql 5.5 application to 5.7.9.

One thing that I'm picking my head about, is mapping the new `performance_schema` to the old `information_schema`, specifically for the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`tables`;
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`columns`;
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`key_column_usage`;
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`schemata`;
```

Any idea where to find these ddl fields?